# Running Multiple sites with multiple domains apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd, httpd.conf, namevirtualhost

I am having a rough time running apache and using multiple domain names

here is a snippet of my config file. I keep getting a error saying that NameVirtualHost has no VirtualHosts. I want them both running on the same IP and I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I've been digging through the documentation for [VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost), [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost), and apache's page about [name based](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) virtual hosting.

That example in the name based page is almost exactly my config! What am I doing wrong?

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.sample1.net
   DocumentRoot /var/www/sample1-net

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example2.net
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example2-net

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because you have 'listen *:80'. It should be `listen 80` or `listen 1.2.3.4:80`.

Comment: I was still using `listen 80` right before upload and was just trying anything and everything at this point. this makes no difference in my testing.

Comment: Then you're going to have to post more of you config? What Distro are you using? Debian based? Do you have sites enabled in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Comment: I'm on centOS. I was not using sites-enabled  just loading the virtualhosts directly in `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: after looking up how `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` work moving the config for each site into it's own [site].conf file in -available then making a link to that file in -enabled I still get the same errors. For what it's worth I got no difference whether i was loading the config in  `httpd.conf`, `conf.d`,  or through `sites-enabled`

Comment: I would really edit your question if I were you. Correct the *:80 mistake, and add more of your configuration. There is more going on here that we can't see.

Comment: I'll post more after I get off of work.